# Pytorch Text AttributeError: ‘BucketIterator’ object has no attribute

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, machine-translation, seq2seq

I’m doing seq2seq machine translation on my own dataset. I have preproceed my dataset using this code.

The problem comes when i tried to split train_data using BucketIterator.split()

```
def tokenize_word(text):
  return nltk.word_tokenize(text)

id = Field(sequential=True, tokenize = tokenize_word, lower=True, init_token="<sos>", eos_token="<eos>")
ti = Field(sequential=True, tokenize = tokenize_word, lower=True, init_token="<sos>", eos_token="<eos>")

fields = {'id': ('i', id), 'ti': ('t', ti)}

train_data = TabularDataset.splits(
    path='/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Tidore/',
    train = 'id_ti.tsv',
    format='tsv',
    fields=fields
)[0]

id.build_vocab(train_data)
ti.build_vocab(train_data)

print(f"Unique tokens in source (id) vocabulary: {len(id.vocab)}")
print(f"Unique tokens in target (ti) vocabulary: {len(ti.vocab)}")

train_iterator = BucketIterator.splits(
    (train_data),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    sort_within_batch = True,
    sort_key = lambda x: len(x.id),
    device = device
)

print(len(train_iterator))

for data in train_iterator:
  print(data.i)
```

This is the result of the code above

```
Unique tokens in source (id) vocabulary: 1425
Unique tokens in target (ti) vocabulary: 1297
2004

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-72-e73a211df4bd> in <module>()
     31 
     32 for data in train_iterator:
---> 33   print(data.i)

AttributeError: 'BucketIterator' object has no attribute 'i'
```

This is the result when i tried to print the train_iterator
[image]

I am very confuse, because i don’t know what key i should use for train iterator. Thank you for your help

Comment: Please provide the question with code snippets instead of images :)

Answer (score 2):

```py
train_iterator = BucketIterator.splits(
  (train_data),
  batch_size = batch_size,
  sort_within_batch = True,
  sort_key = lambda x: len(x.id),
  device = device
)
```

here
Use **BucketIterator** instead of **BucketIterator.splits** when there is only one iterator needs to be generated.

I have met this problem and the method mentioned above works.

Answer (score 1):

According to `torchtext` [documents](https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datasets.html#torchtext.datasets.TranslationDataset), it's better to use `TranslationDataset` to do what is desired!
but if for some reason you prefer to use `TabularDataset` its better to do it like:

```
import nltk
print(nltk.__version__)
from torchtext import data
import torchtext
print(torchtext.__version__)
def tokenize_word(text):
    return nltk.word_tokenize(text)

batch_size = 5

SRC = Field(sequential=True, tokenize = tokenize_word, lower=True, init_token="<sos>", eos_token="<eos>")
TRG = Field(sequential=True, tokenize = tokenize_word, lower=True, init_token="<sos>", eos_token="<eos>")

train = data.TabularDataset.splits(
    path='./data/', train='tr.tsv', format='tsv',
    fields=[('src', SRC), ('trg', TRG)])[0]

SRC.build_vocab(train)
TRG.build_vocab(train)

train_iter = data.BucketIterator(
    train, batch_size=batch_size,
    sort_key=lambda x: len(x.text), device=0)

for item in train_iter:
    print(item.trg)
```

Output:

```
3.6.2
0.6.0
tensor([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        [6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
        [7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
tensor([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        [6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
        [7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

**NOTE:** make sure there is tr.tsv file contains text columns separated by tab, in data directory.
Welcome to stackoverflow & hope it helps :)